# Integral of the form $\int_0^{\infty} \exp{\left(-\frac{(a+bx)^2}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I read another post [Integral of the form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373896/integral-of-the-form-int-0-infty-exp-left-fracabx2x-right-frac?rq=1), which shows the following indefinite integral

$\int \exp\left(-\frac{(a+bx)^2}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3}} $

is solvable. Now, I'm wondering whether

$\int \exp\left(-\frac{(a+bx)^2}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} $

can be solved too?

Is there anybody could give me a hint on that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you actually tried to understand how was that integral solved? Where do you get stuck with this one?

Comment: I think if this is a definite integral, the answers in that post gives a great idea and the definite integral version can be solved. I just got curious whether we can work out this indefinite integral. I didn't have wolfram...so I post this one.

Comment: Maple says this here $$-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{b}}{x}^{3/2}\sqrt {\pi}}{\sqrt {{x}^{3}}\sqrt {a}}
{\rm erf} \left({\frac {\sqrt {a}}{\sqrt {x}}}\right)}
+C$$

Comment: This one is incorrect...anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nyssa I might solve this one... still gets inspration from your previous post. It really helps.