# Extending Feynman's integral trick to indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

### Question

The *Feynman's integral trick* (a.k.a. *differentiation under the integral*) proves to be a powerful tool when dealing with **definite integrals**. However, I have been unable to find a similar *extension* of Feynman's trick in the case of **indefinite integrals**. Thus, I conclude that such an extension is not probably possible, which begs the question **why**? Also, is there such a similar (not the same) trick for inefinite integrals?

### My reasoning

I do have a plausible reason why this trick doesn't work with indefinite integrals. According to my understanding, we are unable to determine the arbitrary *constant of integration* (which could even probably be a function of the integration variable) when re-integrating the differentiated integral. Though, it would be better if anyone could either verify, or falsify, this, or provide a better explanation.

---

### What motivated me to ask the above question?

<sup>The following paragraphs talk about the particular integral which resulted into the above line of thought. Unrelated to the crux of the question, but might be helpful for some context.
 *Do note that I am not asking for a solution which evaluates the following integral, because neither do I not know how to evaluate it, nor is the following integral the spotlight of the question. The question is a general one, concerning every indefinite integral which could possibly solved by Feynman's trick.*</sup>

I encountered the following indefinite integral

$$I=\int \frac{\arctan x}{x^4}\mathrm dx$$

Now I do know of a method to evaluate this integral using *integration by parts*, and it's quite straightforward, however, this time my first thought was to introduce a parameter $b$ such that

$$I(b)=\int \frac{\arctan (bx)}{x^4}\mathrm dx$$

Now differentiating $I(b)$ with respect to $b$ yields

$$\frac{\mathrm d [I(b)]}{\mathrm db}=\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+b^2x^2)x^3}$$

Now substituting $1/x^2$ as $t$, we can easily solve the resultant integral, finally yielding

$$\frac{\mathrm d [I(b)]}{\mathrm db}=-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{b^2}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+b^2\right)+c'$$

And now I am pretty much clueless about what to do next. And this is where I got curious about such a technique for indefinite integrals.

FWIW, the value of the integral comes out to be (obtained using integration by parts) :

> $$I=-\frac{\arctan x}{3x^2}-\frac{1}{6} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\frac{1}{6x^2} + c$$

Comment: why not just transform your indefinite integral into a definite one $I(b,x)=\int_{x_0}^x f(bt)\mathop{dt}$ temporarily ?

Comment: @zwim Hmm... Let's say I do it. What next? I can't see any way to re-integrate the final equation even with this assumption.

Comment: like integrating $\ln(x)$ you start with $x\ln(x)$ then $x^2\ln(x)$, for $b^2\ln(b^2)$ start with $b^3\ln(b^2)$ and add terms (missing after derivation).

Comment: @zwim Alright. But then what about the integration constant. How do I determine that?

Comment: Please stick to either $a$ or $b$ or it will be confusing. Also you should have $I'(b)=-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{b^2}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+b^2\right)+\color{red}{C_1}$ there. Now just integral back as $I(b)=\int I'(b) db$ (which will be something like ($f(b,x)+C_1b+C_2$) and set $b=1$. Also note that a sum of two constants is just another constant, so $C_1+C_2=C$.// Unfortunately for this particular case I don't think it's useful to use Feynman's trick.

Comment: sorry for putting a link, I should leave. https://docdro.id/Y6tcvbX you see that applying Feynman trick (i.e. $g(1)$) and calculating directly ($f(1)$) lead to the same result. The constant $C$ is all the stuff containing $x0$. And you can notice the rest is the same as indefinite integral $I$ you wrote above.

Comment: @ThreeSidedCoin Oops! My bad, corrected :-)

Comment: Very relevant conversation, essentially answering the question: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/conversation/feynmans-trick-for-indefinite-integrals

Comment: Still, I think it's better to stick to what **zwim** suggested above, I rarely encountered indefinite integrals where this is useful, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3583334/515527) integral is definitely one case (originally it was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3563468/515527)).